# Apache server configuration with the right perl version

Tags: apache, perl

So basically my apache server is not using the same perl version as what I have in the os environment and that's why some modules did not get to be used properly. When I checked my error-log, it showed that my intended module cannot be located and it is pointing at `/users/local/perl6`.

When I do `perl -v` in the terminal, it says that `this is perl 5, version 16`. What's the best way to reset my apache server to use the right version of perl?

Comment: Depends on what method it is using to pick up the version of perl it is using. That might be down to the script itself. It might be down to mod_perl (although I don't think it would be if perl6 is involved). It might be down to some part of the Apache configuration.

Comment: @Quentin What's the best way to specify what version of perl I want to pick up in my perl script? (or is there a way?)

Comment: First, look at the shebang in the CGI script you're calling. That's the very first line starting with `#!`.

Comment: @user3669481 In you script you may specify minimum required version: `use v5.16;`. But that does not mean your script will be locked to run only by version you have specified.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to configure `PATH` env variable right. To see  what current env variables are use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
print "\n\n";

use Data::Dumper qw/ pp /;
print pp \%ENV;
```

[How to setup env variables from apache config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html)

For example if you want to install specific version of perl for apache you setup it into `/home/www/perl` directory (Here we use `www` user to run apache sever) and [set `PATH`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

```
SetEnv PATH /home/www/perl/bin
```

**Do not override current `PATH` value if you require it.**

If you want to see what perl is used - run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
print "\n\n";

print `which perl`
```

Answer (score -1):

The particular OS running Apache might have some bearing on the best way. However, assuming no mod_perl, one way that I have used on *nix systems and Windows is to include the entire path to the desired interpreter in the shebang line of the script. That is, the first line of the script should start with "#!" followed by the desired interpreter. For your server, it should be:
    `#!/path/to/Perl5/perl`

Comment: This prevents you from porting scripts to other system where perl maybe in the different path

Comment: I agree that it might be a fair assumption that user3669481 has root access to this box and that it is a *nix box, but setting the path in the environment is only available if you have access to do this. If you are using a low cost hosting company, you likely do not have the required access. The shebang line method is available to more people in more situations; some may even regard it as a superior answer to Eugen Konkov's. This didn't deserve to be down voted.

Comment: Wrong schebang make many problems. How do you automate testing? your assumption maybe used only as last resort and as fast fix. And you should think twice to do that. It is not recommended to use even `#!/usr/bin/perl`. `if you have access to do this` If you read answer carefully and follow links you may notice that `SetEnv` context is `server config, virtual host, directory, **.htaccess**`

Comment: @user3669481 I think we have established that there are at least 2 ways to accomplish your goal. There are reasons to prefer both. Some low cost hosting companies won't allow the config file based solution; they don't let you edit the config files and they disable utilization of .htaccess files. I think their rationale is they can minimize their headaches and costs by locking the box down. That aside, the other solution does have many merits as Eugen Konkov has already described. If you own the box, his solution is great, but if you do; wouldn't it be better to migrate to mod_perl?

Comment: @EugenKonkov I am curious about your automated testing comment. I don't see anything in this question or answers that would preclude automated testing. Are you referring to some constraint imposed by your testing framework?